# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at funcoes.js:2

Tags: javascript

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
        targetOffaset = $(id).offset().top,
        menuHeight = $('nav').innerHeight();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetOffaset -59
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois o cifrão (`$`) é um *alias* (ou atalho) para o jQuery. Por isso é necessário que você adicione o [**jQuery**](https://jquery.com/) antes de chamar `funcoes.js`. Ex:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="funcoes.js"></script>
```

Comment: Valdeir obrigado por ajudar.
Mas já estou puxando os dois:`<script src="funcoes.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`
 
Mais se jogo no console do googlechrome funciona o código.



[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFuId.jpg

Comment: @CarlosHenrique , como eu disse na minha resposta. O jquery **deve** vir antes do funcoes.js. Coloque em seu código **exatamente da forma que fiz** e teste.

Comment: Valdeir cara não acredito que era isso, me toquei agora kkkkkkkkkkkkkk  Muito obrigado cara, vlw mesmo, to rindo aqui por ser isso kkk

Comment: wmsouza, resolvido já,Obrigado :D